# Woocommerce Cart Not Showing Up Properly. 3x Wide than Container

Tags: woocommerce

I installed woocommerce in a custom theme. Everything is working fine - product page, individual product page, checkout page, even the EMPTY cart page. But when i add 1 or more products in the cart and view the cart the CART TABLE expands way out of the main container (almost 3 times the container width). I tried to change the width of the table to 100% to 500px... but it was unresponsive.

What can i do to fix this problem?

Thank you

Comment: Could you paste a URL to your site's cart page.